# Sum of carryover on adding two 4 digit numbers

Tags: c, math

How to get sum of carryover on adding two 4 digit numbers?

An example would be:

Carryovers  111
First 4 digit  9999
2nd   4 digit  7777
       Answer 17776

Here I want to calculate the sum of the carries (answer of summing carries = 3), what should I do?

Comment: Remainder is from a division, not a multiplication. Can you clarify your question and provide a [mcve]? How is this related to the C language? Looks like asking for a simple formula.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What would be the anser for the `55*55`? And the `5*5` is another example or the simplification of the first one?

Comment: @rodrigo: The answer is of course [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) Let's hope we never find out the question!

Comment: I think you mean ***how many*** carryovers occured in a given addition. Not the sum of all carryovers. Is that right?

Comment: No, am asking for sum of the carryover on adding. If carry are 145 the sum is 9 @Ryan B

Comment: 1+4+5 != 19. You know that right?

Comment: Sorry writing error

Comment: So, in your first post the answer would be 3 (1+1+1) and not 111. Right?

Comment: SO is not a coding platform. You won't get any answer unless you show us some of your code first. I did the algorithm, it took me 5 minutes and less than 10 lines of code. So please show us what you did and we'll give you directions.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>
int main() 
    { int num1,num2,sum=0,csum=0,out=0;
    printf("Enter any two 4 digit number : ");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
    while (num1 > 9 || num2 > 9) 
        { 
        int carry1 = num1 % 10; 
        int carry2 = num2 % 10;
        int sum = carry1 + carry2; 
        if (sum > 9) {
            int csum = sum / 10;
                out = out + csum;
            } 
        num1 /= 10; 
        num2 /= 10;
        } 
  printf("The sum of carryovers = %d\n",out);    
     } Ryan B is this right ?

Comment: What if it is multiplication of two number ?

Comment: Please open a new thread for the new question. Besides, multiplication is a bit harder because the carryover might be ***any*** number (in the addition, carryover = 0 or carryover = 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather simple task. You may not know it sice you are new here, but SO is not a coding plateform, so you won't get answers unless you show us **your** code first.

But, since I wanted to try myself on the algorithm, here's a simple answer. I warn you, it won't work on all examples (I won't tell you when this code won't work) and I'm not commenting the code on purpose. I'm smelling the assignment here, so the code is just to give you some pointers, not to make your homework.

**Beware: It's just a skeleton and you won't get a good grade if you copy paste it as it is.**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int numberA = 9999;
    int numberB = 7777;

    int sum_of_carryovers = 0;

    while (numberA > 9 && numberB > 9)
    {
        int digitA = numberA % 10;
        int digitB = numberB % 10;

        int sum = digitA + digitB;

        if (sum > 9)
        {
            sum_of_carryovers += 1;
        }

        numberA /= 10;
        numberB /= 10;
    }

    printf("The sum of carryovers = %d\n", sum_of_carryovers);
}
```